# PHP call function with parameter using array

Tags: php

```
function myFunc($x, $y) {
    echo "x : {$x}";
    echo "y : {$y}";
}
$params = array("y" => 1, "x" => 2);
```

Is it possible to call `myFunc` like using `call_user_func_array` function but the keys of array will automatically set the right parameter in the function? Is there any function to do this or is it possible to create this function? for example :

```
call_func('myFunc', $params);
```

and the result would be like this

```
x : 2
y : 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: I think you'd have to use reflections.

Comment: You can get parameters are `myFunc($param);` and then use `extract($param);`

Comment: @KevinM1 of course, but the result is x -> 1 and y -> 2 for the case above.

Comment: i don't want to use extract for this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a simpler way to do this, but reflection should work too:

```
function call_func_keys($functionName, $args) {
    $f = new ReflectionFunction($functionName);
    $inOrder = array();

    foreach($f->getParameters() as $param) {
        if(array_key_exists($param->name, $args)) {
            $inOrder[] = $args[$param->name];
        } else {
            $inOrder[] = $param->getDefaultValue(); # Will throw a reflection exception if not optional
        }
    }

    call_user_func_array($functionName, $inOrder);
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GAZid2)

Comment: +1 for a good solution that does the job. Not sure I'd use it myself in production though; Reflection always leaves me feeling a bit dirty. What would the performance be like on this?

Comment: wow, that works perfectly. thanks! But, i'm getting a warning
Warning: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7. How to remove it?

Comment: @DarwinGautalius: Sorry, I had a previous version that accidentally used `$param` there; try it again.

Comment: +1 really nice solution, associative arrays as arguments are yummy ;)

Comment: I know, I prefer passing an `array()` to functions instead of arguments, but sometimes it isn't always possible, and your solution fits it very well

Comment: @SDC Reflection is good because it doesn't actually instantiate the class or load the real function, of course it will be a small performance hit, but it'll be negligible, you won't be doing it in a loop with million iterations (i hope), otherwise you wouldn't be using PHP ;)

Comment: @DarwinGautalius: And, in case you're working with optional values, I just changed it so that it handles those better. If not, then ignore this :)

Comment: @minitech : actually, I don't think it would be solved after found an article that said getting parameters name is not possible. thanks again for this great answer! :D
of course it will be very needed for optional parameters. Thx a lot! :D

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED!**

Usually you should use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) function.

And it should be used this way:

```
function myFunc($x, $y) {
   echo "x : {$x}";
   echo "y : {$y}";
}
$params = array("y" => 1, "x" => 2);

call_user_func_array('myFunc', $params);
```

But in your case, you definitely use [`Reflection`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). The @minitech answer is just great.

Comment: `param_arr`: The parameters to be passed to the callback, **as an indexed array**. So no, it doesn't work. http://codepad.viper-7.com/wQ7u8C

Comment: of course, but the result is x -> 1 and y -> 2 for the case above.

Comment: the whole point of the question is the he wants to do it in a way that `call_user_func_array` doesn't seem to support, and asking if there's a way to do it. Your answer doesn't give him anything beyond what he had already tried.